# Selenium unable to click on elements while accessing a webpage using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I'm trying to **scrape** this page. Before getting into the page listings, a Select Location window pops up, so I'm trying to tell selenium to click two buttons in order to access the product listings.

Problem is, Selenium is not able to locate the xpath I'm using to locate this two buttons!

Here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("webdriver/chromedriver.exe")
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get("https://www.indiacashandcarry.com/shop/HomestyleFood")

locationButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="location-list"]/li[1]/h4/a')
groceriesButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="price-list-0"]/ul/li[1]')
locationButton.click()
groceriesButton.click()
```

Here's the site:
https://www.indiacashandcarry.com/shop/HomestyleFood

I'm thinking it is because this popup is on other type of frame, but I couldn't find any iframe index, so I'm a bit lost. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your xpath looks fine.Use `Webdriverwait` to handle dynamic element.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome("webdriver/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.indiacashandcarry.com/shop/HomestyleFood")
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="location-list"]/li[1]/h4/a'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="price-list-0"]/ul/li[1]'))).click()
```

Answer (score 1):

On the website `https://www.indiacashandcarry.com/shop/HomestyleFood` first to `click()` on **Select This Location** associated with **FREMONT** and then `click()` on **Groceries** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  # options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
  driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.indiacashandcarry.com/shop/HomestyleFood")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//h4[contains(., 'Fremont')]/a"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//h5[@class='mtopbot5 ng-binding' and contains(., 'Groceries')]"))).click()
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: Fremont_Groceries]